Errors during downloading metadata for repository 'seconion':- Curl error (37): Couldn't read a file:// file for file:///nsm/repo/repodata/repomd.xml
I tried updating the packages in oracle-linux using
sudo yum update
but it is throwing an error
Errors during downloading metadata for repository 'securityonion':

Curl error (37): Couldn't read a file:// file for file:///nsm/repo/repodata/repomd.xml [Couldn't open file /nsm/repo/repodata/repomd.xml]
Error: Failed to download metadata for repo 'securityonion': Cannot download repomd.xml: Cannot download repodata/repomd.xml: All mirrors were tried

Tried using dnf instead of yum and tried moving the file
sudo mv securityonion.repo securityonion.repo.bak
still having the same issue
